# UrbanAirship crashing Android app

Tags: android, crash, urbanairship.com

I am using UrbanAirship for Push Notifications in my app. But once in a while my app is crashing with android.os.RemoteException .

Reason:An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Stack Trace

---

```
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
2       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
3       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
4       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
5       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
6       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
7       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
8       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
9   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
10      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:258)
11      at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.startService(Unknown Source)
12      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
13      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
14      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
15      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
16      ... 4 more
17  Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
18      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
19      at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getServiceInfo(IPackageManager.java:1617)
20      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:253)
21      ... 9 more
22  java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
23      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:258)
24      at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.startService(Unknown Source)
25      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
26      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
27      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
28      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
29      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
30      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
31      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
32      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
33  Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
34      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
35      at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getServiceInfo(IPackageManager.java:1617)
36      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:253)
37      ... 9 more
38  android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
39      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
40      at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getServiceInfo(IPackageManager.java:1617)
41      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:253)
42      at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.startService(Unknown Source)
43      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
44      at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics$AddEventTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
45      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
46      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
47      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
48      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
49      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
50      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The app is crashing because of the the default value of "Binder".  When you transact large object and use service by "bind service" frequently, the problem will occur.